# Detecting download link in UIWebView

Tags: php, ios, xcode, uiwebview, download

I'm writing an app that needs to detect if UIWebView is navigating to the address of an IPA file stored on a web server.

**Example:**

http://www.website.com/ipa.ipa

Obviously under normal circumstances it would show an error when navigating to the address of an IPA, 
but for my app I need to be able to capture the address of the IPA and store it as a `NSString` to be sent to a server for processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of method in UIWebViewDelegate protocol it may help:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

just set your controller to webview's delegate and implement above method.